# Ract and force redirect on not allowed route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to redirect a user which is trying to access a route which is not accessible based on a role.

I thought that `<Redirect>` component will do that:

```
{appRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
    if(prop.roles.includes("appuser")) {
        return (
            <Route
                exact
                path={prop.path}
                component={prop.component}
                key={key}
            />
        );
    }
    else {
        return (
            <Redirect to={"/home"} />
        )
    }
})}
```

Any tips on that?

Comment: Is your current code working and what problem do you have?

Comment: @ZivojinMilutinovic code above is working except instead redirect will display empty page (not allowed route)